# Convert nvarchar to bigint in Sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nvarchar, bigint

I want insert all rows of a table into another table, and I also want convert a `nvarchar` field into `bigint`, but when I use `convert(bigint, col1)` SQL Server shows an error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar
>   to bigint

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: "How can i fix this problem?
" - simple. remove the data that can't be converted to biginteger

Comment: How Can I Remove Non numeric data automatically...?

Comment: failing having a magic wand, by writing TSQL to remove it!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could try to use `ISNUMERIC` to determine those rows that are indeed numeric:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET BigIntColumn = CAST(NVarcharColumn AS BIGINT)
WHERE ISNUMERIC(NVarcharColumn) = 1
```

That would convert those rows that can be converted - the others need to be dealt with manually.

Comment: This will fail for decimals stored as strings: SELECT CAST('.1' AS BIGINT)
WHERE ISNUMERIC('.1') = 1

Comment: just to add to BD's comment, char(36) and chars 43-46, 48-57, 92, 128, 160, 162-165 all evaluate to 1 being numeric.  The real kicker is in a where or join statement where you filter out all the non-numeric values logically first, at the end do a convert statement, and this error still occurs (ignores short circuit and evaluates whole line.)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert bigint to nvarchar not vice versa 
cast(Other_Column_name as nvarchar) not cast (Column_Name as bigint)

Answer (score 0):

***you can try this:***

```
CAST(CAST(col1 as NUMERIC) as BIGINT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I convert navrchar value of column into bigInt and than perform Addition of thos two columns find blow :

```
SELECT (CAST(col1 AS BIGINT) + CAST(col2 AS BIGINT)) AS TotalValue from tableName
```